# What does the TypeError: _n6.split is not a function (it is undefined) mean?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have tried and debugged different things and came to the conclusion that this is the problem

```
  const artistsCollectionRef = collection(db, "Artists");

  onSnapshot(artistsCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
      const updatedData = change.doc.data();
      const eventId = updatedData.Events;

      const eventRef = doc(db, "Events", eventId);
      if (change.type === "modified") {
        updateDoc(eventRef, {
          Artist: updatedData.Name,
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

I'm using Firebase V10 and Expo, sorry if this isn't helpful it's my first time posing on Stackoverflow.

I tried to make it so that when data changes in one Firebase document it also changes in another document, I have more code for this but this code is the problem. I'm using useSnapshot to check when a change is made in the artists document, then it needs to check what changed and update the event document based off of what changed

Comment: what is the real issue, then ? What are you trying to achieve your question is really unspecific… please edit it to make more sense we don’t read minds here.

Comment: @Richardson I edited it, I hope this explains it a bit better.

Comment: Are you sure const eventId = updatedData.Events;
will render the doc id ???????

Comment: @Richardson yes  every bit should theoretically work that's why I find this do weird. I'll try to edit the post to upload more code tomorrow.

Comment: You might want to `console.log(eventId)` to validate the assumption, or add a if (eventId) { ... do something with it }` conditional to check it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you! It was fairly simple to fix, apparently there was a problem wxith the eventRef variable even though it wasn't undefined, but i managed  to fix it like this:  if (change.type === "modified") {
            for (const eventId of eventIds) {
              const eventRef = doc(db, "Events", eventId);
              await updateDoc(eventRef, {
                Artist: updatedData.Name,
              });
            }
          }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the eventRef variable, I can't figure out what it was because it was defined. But i managed to work around it by doing this:

```
const updatedData = change.doc.data();
      const eventIds = updatedData.Events;

      if (change.type === "modified") {
        for (const eventId of eventIds) {
          const eventRef = doc(db, "Events", eventId);
          await updateDoc(eventRef, {
            Artist: updatedData.Name,
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).